Power BI: Ribbon Chart changed by Slicer
I’m new to Power BI.
I have a table like this:



Type
Food
Hygiene
NFI




City
1
2
1


City
3
1
1


Village
1
1
2


City
2
2
1


Village
1
3
1


City
3
3
2



I want to have a Ribbon chart with:
Ribbons (Legend): Food, Hygiene and NFI
X-axis: 1 2 3
Y-axis: Count of proper X, so for Food it is like
o    
o   o
o o o
1 2 3
And I want also have a Slicer for Type, so if I select City, Food ribbon changes:
    o
o o o
1 2 3
I made a Calculated table
T1 = 
VAR UniqueVals = 
    DISTINCT(UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(main, "Value", main[Food]),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(main, "Value", main[Hygiene]),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(main, "Value", main[NFI]),
    ))
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        UniqueVals,
        "Food", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(main), main[Food] = EARLIER([Value])),
        "Hygiene", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(main), main[Hygiene] = EARLIER([Value])),
        "NFI", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(main), main[NFI] = EARLIER([Value])),
    )

which gives me what I need for a chart. Than I found out that Slicer doesn't affect calculated tables. Pity!
It looks like measures are recalculating. But how can I use it here? Or are there any other ways?

You can create with values 1, 2, and 3
GeneratedTable = 
GENERATESERIES(1, 3, 1)


Then create 3 measures :
Food Count = 
    VAR xAxisValue = SELECTEDVALUE(GeneratedTable[Value])
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(MyTable),
        MyTable[Food] = xAxisValue
    )


Hygiene Count = 
VAR xAxisValue = SELECTEDVALUE(GeneratedTable[Value])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(MyTable),
    MyTable[Hygiene] = xAxisValue
)


NFI Count = 
VAR xAxisValue = SELECTEDVALUE(GeneratedTable[Value])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(MyTable),
    MyTable[NFI] = xAxisValue
)


Then drag Value from the Generated table to the X-axis and the measures to the Y-axis :

Then you can add the Type as a slicer :



